# Send Sharepoint Alert style email via SPD Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, alert

I am trying to set up a workflow that sends an email to the assigned person and those contributing to a list item when the content of that item is changed. Currently I have it working, but I am getting complaints that they don't know what has changed and reading the whole document is time consuming. The Sharepoint Alert system sends a nice email that shows what was edited so you can easily see the changes. My question is how can i get the content found in that Alert into my Workflow email?[image: Alert Image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to do something like this is via an event receiver that hooks into the `ItemAdding()` or `ItemUpdating()` events.  You would still have to build and send the mail in your code though.  Here is some information on [creating Event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) in general and some on the details of [those particular events](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122).  For sending the email, you would need some [code like this](http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/11/25/programatically-sending-mail-in-sharepoint.aspx) - note, I prefer using option #2 in that post as it uses objects that allow for much greater control over the message itself.

If you are feeling bold, you could tap into the change history for an item and build everything yourself via custom workflow action.  However, this can be pretty hairy.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a solution like this one:
[How can I create custom Alerts for external email addresses?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76085/how-can-i-create-custom-alerts-for-external-email-addresses/76086#76086)

This solution also falls into the pretty hairy category but it is totally do-able.